# keeping the text hint at the bottom row of the textArea - cn1

Tags: codenameone

I've a design where the hint of the text area is at the bottom. Label.LEFT, Label.RIGHT, Label.CENTER etc works. But Label.BOTTOM doesn't. TextArea has 4 rows. How can I achieve that ie. keeping hint at the last row of textArea?

Code:

```
TextArea remarksArea = new TextArea();
remarksArea.setConstraint(TextField.NON_PREDICTIVE);
remarksArea.setRows(4);
remarksArea.setGrowByContent(false);
remarksArea.setHint("Description Here");remarksArea.getHintLabel().setUIID("TextField");
remarksArea.getHintLabel().getAllStyles().setFgColor(0x000000);
remarksArea.getHintLabel().getAllStyles().setAlignment(Label.BOTTOM);
```

Answer (score 0):

Alignment only supports center/left/right. The bottom/top constants are intended for other uses such as label/icon positioning in set text position.

You can "fake" this UI by using a layered layout and placing a label on top of the text area.